# wkWebView load request fail with Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

in `WKWebView` on loading url get

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey="https://xxxxxxxxx",
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey="https://xxxxxxxxx",
>   _WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=}

I got this error not always but randomly

Answer (score 0):

-999 error code means NSURLErrorCancelled.

This happens when the past request is cancelled.

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailNavigation navigation: WKNavigation, withError error: NSError) {

    print(error)

}
```

Comment: thanks @abecedario for your answer but in my case request goes only once to load, there is no multiple requests